# Was there a Cold War era Russian safe haven city for politicians and scientists?

Tags: soviet-union, russia, cold-war

I remember learning about a Russian city where, during the Cold War, top politicians and scientists and their families would be evacuated to. It would have existed as a normal city outside of Cold War era [ICBM range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile) from the US, and I believe it still had the children of the high ranking people living there in the 1990's and 2000's, but I'm not sure about currently.

I've tried searching, but I can't seem to find anything that supports this. Is there something to it?

Comment: Where did you learn about this place? I would have thought that evacuating all of your top politicians and scientists to the same place raises the possibility that a single strike in the right place would wipe them all out.

Comment: "During the cold war" (secret cities, ongoing work/research) or "in case the bomb is released" (emergency shelter, futile measure to try to ensure survival)?

Comment: Steve, I heard about it from my high school history teacher who said he'd been there and apparently some of the people stayed there. And Lang, I believe it was during the cold war, as in a secret city, but I could be off the mark on that

Comment: Please preferably [edit] the Q with updates (instead of commenting). So that means, 'they' would have been/_were_ 'there' actually for quite a while, in 'peace time', regularly, not as a planned option for eventualities?

Comment: Thanks Lang, updated it

Comment: Possibly related? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city

Comment: Safe city where the children of the elite are living? That would be Geneva, Switzerland.

Comment: @MCW This is not secret: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile

Comment: When first seeing the title question, I interpreted "safe haven" as meaning safe from Soviet political oppression -- a place administered more [liberally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism), where people could enjoy some freedom of speech and where Western influence was more tolerated, perhaps analogous to Hong Kong (circa early 2000s) for China. A retreat for elite "politicians and scientists" to be able to party, blow off steam, and openly discuss reality, without tipping off the brainwashed masses in the rest of the country. Obviously this wasn't what you meant, but it seems amusing.

Answer (score 32):

**Most likely it's a myth.**

First, nothing is "outside of ICBM range".

The so-called "[closed cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city)" were primarily nuclear production or research sites.<sup>1</sup> They were presumably on the primary hit list and were hardly a "safe haven" in case of a nuclear war. In peacetime though living there was a privilege as the supply standards were (much) higher than elsewhere.<sup>2</sup> But this was hardly a concern for "children of the high ranking people".

If such "safe haven" city existed, it would surely be known and would be added to the hit list.

Moscow was the [only city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Ballistic_Missile_Treaty) (with surroundings) protected by the [anti-ICBM system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-35_anti-ballistic_missile_system). So it was probably the safer place to be (of the cities with acceptable living standards for such people).

Personally, after living in the USSR (and in a "closed city"), I've never heard of such arrangement. Everyone wanted to be in Moscow.

Surely, emergency evacuation plans existed. But the situation was never dire enough (after the early 60s at least) to start evacuating children preemptively.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with many border cities or larger industrial cities were foreigners were not admitted. They often went under the same moniker of a "closed city". But the dozen or so "real ones" were closed even for Soviet citizens. They usually had code names and were not even shown on maps.

<sup>2</sup> Except perhaps Moscow, another very privileged city with restricted access (for migration).

Comment: Wait...so someone driving through the USSR could presumably just stumble over an entire city that wasn't on maps and they weren't supposed to know about?

Comment: @T.E.D. - Los Alamos was a closed town until 1957. Even though people know about it, unless you had a pass you got turned back at the gate, some ways away from the town itself. In the same way I suspect that USSR closed towns had access control well before one got to the town. And folks just driving around Russia for fun was much less prevalent than in the US.

Comment: Such towns exist today. We just call them military bases.

Comment: @candied_orange - I happen to have a day job that occasionally sends me to military bases here in the US. They are all (well the ones they'll let me go to anyway) on google maps, including their internal street patterns. I've been known to use google maps to get myself to the correct building. I do know of at least one that probably isn't, but you have to get there by plane.

Comment: @T.E.D. yes. Entire cities were completely fenced off. Of course, locals knew about it, but for any Soviet citizen, just stumbling over an unidentified fence in the middle of nowhere wouldn't be surprising. [Sometimes](https://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=58.639526&lon=59.831200&z=13&m=w&show=/115022/Lesnoy), there would be an adjacent 'normal' town with its train station etc. which was on the map (think about West Berlin disappearing from maps). Of course, nowadays you can (virtually) explore such places in [painful detail](https://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=57.273800&lon=60.110750&z=15&m=w).

Comment: The way you're speaking of Moscow in the USSR seems to parallel Pyongyang being the coveted city of privilege for those on good terms with the government in North Korea.  I guess it makes sense though, since the USSR, from what I understand, did at least a decent amount to dictate people's jobs and locations.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I don't think someone could just _"... [drive] through the USSR could presumably just stumble over an entire city"_ back in the Soviet days.  You needed a pass for internal travel (from memory).  I know that even now (well, maybe 5-10 years ago), as a foreigner, if you get a visa to enter the country, the visa includes where you can go.  My daughter spent 8 weeks in a Siberian town for training and I suggested she take the Trans Siberian Express one way (there was a stop there).  She didn't want to go, but she asked and was told that it would require a new visa

Comment: @Flydog57 - True. Still they had long-haul truckers. I remember reading that it was actually one of the better-paying Soviet era jobs (presumably because most people didn't want to do it, perhaps at least partially because the consequences of taking a wrong turn could be rather dire).

Comment: @T.E.D. And will be immediately shot out by machine gun. This is typical mockery. Every restricted area in the world (possible, your workplace too) has a checkpoint which purpose is to restrict unauthorized entrance. I guess, if you come to work without your pass, it will not be rather dire, except penalty for truancy.

Comment: @Flydog57, no, it wasn't that hard. As a Soviet citizen, you may have needed a pass (or local residence) close to the border, but otherwise travelling throughout the USSR was easy and didn't need permission. (Everyone had and needed a passport with the residence address stamped, though). Proportionally, not many could "drive through the USSR" simply because not many had a car, and the road infrastructure was poor (especially farther east). But kayaking, mountain climbing, multi-day bushwalking, etc. was extremely popular, and in such travels one could easily encounter an unexpected fence.

Comment: @T.E.D. given the sheer size of Russia, it's not difficult to hide an entire city, before the time of global satellite coverage (early satellites didn't take whole-globe pictures, they were pointed at specific locations, took a small number of pictures, and dropped them off via parachute capsules).